# Como contar quantos elementos um array possui?

Tags: c, array

Tenho um `array` de 10 posições que é preenchido através de uma função,

```
ARMultiEachMarkerInfoT marcadoresVisiveis[10];
```

sempre antes de adicionar elementos ao `array`, a função limpa todos os elementos e preenche de novo. Quero saber qual a melhor maneira de contar quantos elementos o `array` possui, tentei algo do tipo: contar quantos elementos não nulos o *array* possui e incrementar um contador mas não obtive sucesso.

Segue a função:

```
void ReposicionaObjetos(){
    int i;

    //Limpa o array
    memset(marcadoresVisiveis, 0, sizeof marcadoresVisiveis);

    //Preenche o array
    for( i = 0; i < config->marker_num; i++ ) {
        if( config->marker[i].visible >= 0 ){
            marcadoresVisiveis[i] = config->marker[i];
        }
    }

    //... Saber quantos elementos o array possui...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria algo assim:

```
void ReposicionaObjetos(){
    int contaElementosValidos = 0;
    memset(marcadoresVisiveis, 0, sizeof marcadoresVisiveis);
    for int (i = 0; i < config->marker_num; i++) {
        if (config->marker[i].visible >= 0 ){
            marcadoresVisiveis[i] = config->marker[i];
            contaElementosValidos++;
        }
    }
    //faz o que precisa com contaElementosValidos
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/CountValidElements.c).

Tenho serias dúvidas se esta abordagem de limpar *array* e popular novamente é a correta, mas como não dei o contexto não posso falar muito.

Comment: Compartilho as dúvidas sobre limpar o array, mas por hora, é suficiente. Simples solução, às vezes foge aos olhos e tentamos procurar algo mais complexo ou simplesmente não sabemos como procurar, enfim obrigado, funcionou exatamente como esperado.